# Choosing menu elements after .delay()

Tags: jquery, html, menu, delay, slidedown

I spend many hours thinking how to deal with it, but no results.
I have some HTML code:

```
<aside class="column-left">
        <ul class="menu">
           <li><a href="#">Cukierki</a>
                <ul class="subMenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Cukierki</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lemoniada</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Wata cukrowa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Wlochate Nogi</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Lemoniada</a>
                <ul class="subMenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Leonidas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Britney</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Herkules</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Vader</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Wata cukrowa</a>
                <ul class="subMenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Cukierki</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lemoniada</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Wata cukrowa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Drewno z metalu</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Gówno</a></li>
         </ul>
    </aside>
```

and jQuery code:

```
PROJECT = {
init: function(){
    this.showMenu();
},
showMenu: function(){
  $('.column-left .menu li').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $(this).find('.subMenu').stop(true,true).slideDown();
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $(this).find('.subMenu').stop(true,true).delay(1000).slideUp();
    }
  })
 }
}
$(document).ready(function(){  
  PROJECT.init();
});
```

When I'm choosing `li` from top to bottom, everything is OK, but inversely I need to wait 1 second until "new" `.subMenu` slide down. Effect that i want to obtain is changing .subMenu in exact time when i hover 'li'. I need delay to reach .subMenu, which is remote from 'li'.
What i did wrong?:D

Comment: Please try to be a bit more clear about what the problem is? If you don't want the delay then just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood:

Just change this (remove the `delay(1000)` ):

```
$(this).find('.subMenu').stop(true,true).delay(1000).slideUp();
```

to

```
$(this).find('.subMenu').stop(true,true).slideUp();
```

Not sure what is your issue.